# Newsletter Archive?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, newsletter

I think I've done due diligence in searching, and I cannot find a StackOverflow newsletter archive.  Does one exist?  If not, would it be possible?

Comment: Stack Overflow publishes newsletters?

Comment: Oh.  [Never mind.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/stack-exchange-site-newsletters/)

Comment: Yes they do.  I use them to kill those periods of time when I'm not quite motivated enough to do real work, but need more stimuli than than CNN or Drudge provide.  I've read all the ones I received, but for some reason I only get them sporadically.  So, I'd like some more please...

Comment: @RobertHarvey The newsletter is pretty well hidden. It took me almost 4 months of usage before I "discovered" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't exist, mainly because every newsletter is different:

- Monday's Stack Overflow newsletter is different from Tuesday's newsletter, because the "top new questions this week" and the "can you answer these?" questions vary from day to day.
- Each newsletter recipient gets a different set of "can you answer these?" questions. This way, we don't direct thousands of people to the same few unanswered questions.